# Calculate P = $720\cot x$, $x \in$ $[0;\frac{\pi}{2}]$

Tags: trigonometry

Given $x$ such as $\sqrt{4+1020\sin^2\frac{x}{2}}+\sqrt{21025-9792\sin\frac{x}{2}\cos\frac{x}{2}}=145$ and $x\in [0;\frac{\pi}{2}]$. Calculate the value of $P=720\cot x$.

And I can modify the condition is $\sqrt{514-510\cos x}+\sqrt{21025-4896\sin x}=145$.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.